# Display Microsoft Access "OLE Object" in my application

Tags: delphi, ole

I have an an Access database that contains an OLE Object field.  I need to extract the contents of this field as an image.  It does not matter what type was originally placed in the OLE Field.  I just need an image that represents what that object looks like.

The main goal of this is to move away from the OLE Object field to a more standard image stored in a blob field.

I have found some example code that parses the blob and tries to extract the underlying file.  I am really looking for something that uses the OLE objects as they were intended instead of trying to work around them.

There are two similar questions on stackoverflow:
[Converting an OLE Image Object from MS Access for use in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416497/converting-an-ole-image-object-from-ms-access-for-use-in-net)
[Extract OLE Object (pdf) from Access DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029340/extract-ole-object-pdf-from-access-db)

I'm opening this question mainly as a place to post my current Delphi code to see if there is a better way than my current code and to help others if not.

I am using Delphi 2007 but code in any language would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is the solution that I am using.  The starting point for this came from the [Ms Access Ole Fields on the about.com site](http://forums.about.com/ab-delphi/messages?lgnF=y&msg=1865.1).

A few notes:

- Access seems to store the object using the OLE1 standard not the OLE2.  I could not find any confirmation of this anywhere other than the post mentioned above.
- Access appends its own header in front of the OLE1 field.  Again I did not find any documentation other than the post.
- I could not find a way to use the OLE1 object directly, I needed to convert it to an OLE2 object.  In order to do that I needed and OLE1 stream which did not seem to be implemented in the VCL or Win API anywhere. The implementation is taken directly from the post, I can't say I understand everything it is doing.

Once you have a IOLEObject in had you can use the OleDraw function to draw to your own canvas.  At that point you have an image and are off and running.  If you just want to display the object you can use the TOLEContainer component and let it deal with the drawing.

Here is the code that uses the unit.  I have an ADO table with a field object of type TBlobField named AdoTable1Photo.

```
procedure TForm2.ADOTable1AfterScroll(DataSet: TDataSet);
var
  Bmp: TBitmap;
  Jpg: TJpegImage;

  OleObject: IOleObject;
  DataObject: IDataObject;
  CreateInfo: TCreateInfo;
begin

  if AdoTable1Photo.BlobSize = 0 then
    exit;

  OleObject := OleFieldToObject(AdoTable1Photo);

  // If you want to save out an image file draw let the ole object draw to
  // a bitmap canvas and then save the results.  Could be used for converting
  // a field to a true image blob instead of a OLE Object type.
  Bmp := TBitmap.Create();
  Jpg := TJpegImage.Create();

  try
    DrawOleOnBmp(OleObject, Bmp);
    Jpg.Assign(Bmp);
    Jpg.SaveToFile('C:\temp\test.jpg');
  finally
    Bmp.Free;
    Jpg.Free;
  end;

  // If just trying to display the results without converting you can attach
  // the OleObject to a OleContainer component that will handle the drawing.
  // I could not find an easy way to do this directly.  I needed to use the
  // IDataObject interace with the CreateInfo record.

  if Succeeded(OleObject.QueryInterface(IDataObject, DataObject)) then
  begin
    // Load the OLE Container control by using the IDataObject
    CreateInfo.CreateType := ctFromData;
    CreateInfo.ShowAsIcon := false;
    CreateInfo.DataObject := DataObject;
    OleContainer.CreateObjectFromInfo(CreateInfo);
  end;

  OleObject := nil;
end;
```

And here is the unit that is converting the field to the IOleObject.  The hard part is extracting the stream splitting out the header and converting it to an OLE2 object.  Once that is done there are really only two functions I am using: OLELoad and OLEDraw.

```
unit MSAccessOleObject;

interface
uses ActiveX, Windows, Classes, ComObj, DB, Graphics;

  // This file is a modified version of the source code posted here:
  // http://forums.about.com/ab-delphi/messages?lgnF=y&msg=1865.1

  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Converted from Ole.h
  // 
  // Used inside from OleConvertOLESTREAMToIStorage OLE Function
  // As far I know the Access Converts the OLE2 objects in OLE1 Objects
  //
  // So for read this Kind of field we must covert the OLE1 format
  // to OLE2 format so we need the OleConvertOLESTREAMToIStorage
  // and to write an OLE object to Field we need the
  // OleConvertIStorageToOLESTREAM OLE function.
  // The code here is only for reading "Ole Object" fields, but it coudld adapted
  // to write them as well. 
  //
  // OLE.h define a OLE stream that uses a vtable and callback functions. I
  // could not find a class in the VCL that implemented the OLE v1 Stream.
  type
    POleStreamVtbl = ^TOleStreamVtbl;
    TOleStreamVtbl = record
      Get: Pointer;
      Put: Pointer;
    end;

    POle1Stream = ^TOle1Stream;
    TOle1Stream = record
      pvt: POleStreamVtbl;
      lpData: Pointer; // Link to Data in .MDB file
      dwSize: Integer; // OLE Stream length (relative to position)
    end;

    POleStream = ^TPOleStream;
    TPOleStream = record
      lpstbl: POleStreamVtbl;
    end;

  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //    Microsoft Access Field Header
  //
  //  Access adds header information in front of the actual OLE stream.
  //  We need to read it to get the size in order to find the start of
  //  the actual OLE stream.
  type
    TKind=record
      case Integer of
        0: (oot: DWord); // OLE Object type code (OT_LINK, OT_EMBEDDED, OT_STATIC)
        1: (lobjTyp: LongInt); // in our case: OT_EMBEDDED
      end;

    PAccessOleObjectHeader=^TAccessOleObjectHeader;
    TAccessOleObjectHeader = record
      typ: WORD;       // Type signature (0x1C15)
      cbHdr: WORD;     // sizeof(struct OLEOBJECTHEADER) + cchName +cchClass
      lobjType: TKind; // OLE Object Type Code (OT_STATIC, OT_LINKED,OT_EMBEDDED)
      cchName: WORD;   // Count of characters in object Name (CchSz(szName) + 1))
      cchClass: WORD;  // Count of characters in class Name  (CchSz(szClss) + 1))
      ibName: WORD;    // Offset of object name in structure  (sizeof(OLEOBJECTHEADER)
      ibClass: WORD;   // Offset of class name in structure  (ibName +cchName)
      ptSize: TSmallPoint; // Original size of Object (MM_HIMETRIC)
    end;


  function CreateOle1Stream(pStm: IStream; dwSize: Integer): POle1Stream;
  procedure DeleteOle1Stream(var Ole1Stream: POle1Stream);

  // Callback Functions for OLE1 Stream
  function Get(OleStream: POLESTREAM; Pb:Pointer; cb:Integer): Integer; stdcall;
  function Put(OleStream: POLESTREAM; const Pb:Pointer; cb:Integer): Integer; stdcall;

  function OleFieldToObject(AdoField: TBlobField): IOleObject;
  procedure DrawOleOnBmp(Ole: IOleObject; Bmp: TBitmap);

implementation

uses Sysutils;

{
  CreateOle1Stream
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
function CreateOle1Stream(pStm:IStream; dwSize:Integer): POLE1Stream;
var
  cb: Int64;
begin
  Result := new(POle1Stream);
  Result.pvt := new(POleStreamVtbl);
  Result.pvt.Get := @Get;
  Result.pvt.Put := @Put;
  Result.dwSize := dwSize;
  Result.lpData := Pointer(pStm);

  // Seek to the start of the stream
  IStream(Result.lpData).Seek(0,STREAM_SEEK_SET,cb);
end;


{
  DeleteOle1Stream
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
procedure DeleteOle1Stream(var Ole1Stream: POle1Stream); // Dispose then OLE1 Stream
begin
  if Ole1Stream = Nil then
    exit;

  Dispose(Ole1Stream^.pvt);
  Dispose(Ole1Stream);
end;

{
  Put
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Callback function for Ole1Stream
}
function Put(OleStream: POLESTREAM; const Pb:Pointer; cb:Integer): Integer; stdcall;
Var
  pStream: POle1Stream;
  ulBytesWritten: longInt;
begin
  pStream:=POle1Stream(OleStream);

  if (pStream = Nil) or (pStream^.lpData=Nil) or (pb=Nil) then
  begin
    Result:=0;
    exit;
  end;

  ulBytesWritten:=0;
  if IStream(pStream^.lpData).Write(Pb,cb,@ulBytesWritten) <> S_OK then
  begin
    Result:=0;
    exit;
  end;

  pStream^.dwSize:=pStream^.dwSize+ulBytesWritten;
  Result:=cb;
end;

{
  Get
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Callback function for Ole1Stream
}
function Get(OleStream: POLESTREAM; Pb: Pointer; cb: Integer): Integer; stdcall;
Var
  pStream: POle1Stream;
  ulBytesRead: LongInt;
begin
  pStream := POle1Stream(OleStream);
  if (pStream=Nil) or (pStream^.lpData=Nil) or (pStream^.dwSize < cb)
  then
  begin
    Result := 0;
    exit;
  end;

  ulBytesRead := 0;
  if IStream(pStream^.lpData).Read(pb, cb, @ulBytesRead) <> S_OK then
  begin
    Result := 0;
    exit;
  end;

  pStream^.dwSize := pStream^.dwSize-ulBytesRead;
  Result := cb;

end;

{
  OleFieldToObject
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Pass in the ADO field of the "OLE Object" type and get the IOleObject
  interface back.  You can then attached that object to a OleContanier and
  let it draw itself or use the DrawOleOnBmp function to get your own bitmap
  that can be used by itself.
}
function OleFieldToObject(AdoField: TBlobField): IOleObject;
var

  AccessHeader: TAccessOleObjectHeader;

  FullAdoStream: TMemoryStream;
  ObjectStream: TMemoryStream;

  StreamAdapter: TStreamAdapter;
  StreamInterface: IStream;
  Ole1Stream: POle1Stream;

  OleBytes: ILockBytes;
  OleStorage: IStorage;
  OleObject: IOleObject;

begin

  FullAdoStream := nil;
  ObjectStream := nil;
  StreamAdapter := nil;
  StreamInterface := nil;
  Ole1Stream := nil;

  try
    // We need a IStorage Interface that will be used to load the OLEObject
    OleCheck( CreateILockBytesOnHGlobal(0, true, OleBytes) );
    OleCheck( StgCreateDocfileOnILockBytes(OleBytes,
      STGM_Create or STGM_READWRITE or STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE or STGM_DIRECT,  0, OleStorage) );


    // We need to get the data out of the field.  Microsoft Access stores a OLE1 field
    // and not the current OLE2 format.  It also adds it's own header on the object.
    // We need to - extract the stream, remove the header, wrap the stream in an
    // IStreamInterface, wrap that inside and OLE1Stream object.

    FullAdoStream := TMemoryStream.Create();
    AdoField.SaveToStream(FullAdoStream);

    FullAdoStream.Seek(0, soBeginning);
    FullAdoStream.ReadBuffer(AccessHeader, sizeof(TAccessOleObjectHeader));

    // We could check if AccessHeader.typ = $1C15 but if the format is not
    // right something will go wrong later.


    // Seek past the header and then copy the rest of the stream to a new stream.
    FullAdoStream.Seek(AccessHeader.cbHdr, soBeginning);
    ObjectStream := TMemoryStream.Create();
    ObjectStream.CopyFrom(FullAdoStream, FullAdoStream.Size - FullAdoStream.Position);

    StreamAdapter := TStreamAdapter.Create(ObjectStream, soReference);
    StreamInterface := StreamAdapter as IStream;
    Ole1Stream := CreateOle1Stream(StreamInterface, ObjectStream.Size);

    // Now convert the OLE1 stream to OLE2 (IStorage) and load the IOleObject
    // This function seems to be slow, but I can't find anything to change
    // or any other function to use. 
    OleCheck( OleConvertOLESTREAMToIStorage(Ole1Stream, OleStorage, Nil) );
    OleCheck( OleLoad(OleStorage, IOleObject, nil, OleObject) );

  finally
    DeleteOle1Stream(Ole1Stream);
    StreamInterface := nil;
    StreamAdapter := nil;
    ObjectStream.Free;
    FullAdoStream.Free;
  end;

  result := OleObject;

end;


{
  DrawOleOnBmp
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Take a OleObject and draw it to a bitmap canvas.  The bitmap will be sized
  to match the normal size of the OLE Object.
}
procedure DrawOleOnBmp(Ole: IOleObject; Bmp: TBitmap);
var
  ViewObject2: IViewObject2;
  ViewSize: TPoint;
  AdjustedSize: TPoint;

  DC: HDC;
  R: TRect;
begin

  if Succeeded(Ole.QueryInterface(IViewObject2, ViewObject2)) then
  begin
    ViewObject2.GetExtent(DVASPECT_CONTENT, -1, nil, ViewSize);

    DC := GetDC(0);
    AdjustedSize.X := MulDiv(ViewSize.X, GetDeviceCaps(DC, LOGPIXELSX), 2540);
    AdjustedSize.Y := MulDiv(ViewSize.Y, GetDeviceCaps(DC, LOGPIXELSY), 2540);
    ReleaseDC(0, DC);

    Bmp.Height := AdjustedSize.Y;
    Bmp.Width := AdjustedSize.X;

    SetRect(R, 0, 0, Bmp.Width, Bmp.Height);

    OleDraw(Ole, DVASPECT_CONTENT, Bmp.Canvas.Handle, R);
  end
  else
  begin
    raise Exception.Create('Could not get the IViewObject2 interfact on the OleObject');
  end;

end;

end.
```