# How extract image from OLE object from MS-Access?

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, jdbc, ole

I have the MS Access databese with images fields and i need to extract this images to byte array. The problem is that into database images is inside OLE container, and when i get images from database as BLOB, i have OLE container with image inside and i cannot display and print this image. I've try this [Converting an OLE Image Object from MS Access for use in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416497/converting-an-ole-image-object-from-ms-access-for-use-in-net) way to extract images, but it works only with BMP images inside the container. I use the JDBC-ODBC bridge.

So, can anybody help me?

Comment: There are other examples of removing the header bits : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029340/extract-ole-object-pdf-from-access-db

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it but maybe this could work: http://poi.apache.org/.

From the site:

> The project provides APIs for the OLE2 Filesystem (POIFS) and OLE2
>   Document Properties (HPSF).